# VB.NET exception issue

Tags: vb.net, exception, loops

I am working on my homework.  My assignment is to create an application that reads a file the user selects into memory.  In this case it is reading in a structure of array objects that includes a country and it's matching abbreviation.  The file loads correctly and when I use the application to search by country or abbreviation, and it finds the matching country or abbreviation in the file it displays it as it should.  However, when I enter information incorrectly and it does not find a match it is supposed to go to the If Not Found block of code and bring up a message box.  Instead it crashes and throws me an exception that says:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I do not understand what is happening.  Please look over my code and assist if you can.  thank You.

```
Option Strict On

'import a file
Imports System.IO

Public Class frmCountry

'Module Structure
Structure Countries
    Dim Names As String
    Dim Abbreviation As String
End Structure

'module array
Dim Country(257) As Countries
'file reader
Private sr As StreamReader

'search button click event
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    'event level variables
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim Counter As Integer

    'looks for entry match
    If rdoAbbrev.Checked = True Then
        Do Until Found Or Counter > 256
            Found = Country(Counter).Abbreviation.ToUpper = txtAbbrev.Text.ToUpper
            If Found Then
                txtCountry.Text = Country(Counter).Names
            Else
                Counter += 1
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        Do Until Found Or Counter > 256
            Found = Country(Counter).Names.ToUpper = txtCountry.Text.ToUpper
            If Found Then
                txtAbbrev.Text = Country(Counter).Abbreviation
            Else
                Counter += 1
            End If
        Loop

    End If
    'match not found response
    If Not Found Then
        MessageBox.Show("This is not a valid entry.", "NO MATCH FOUND", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        If rdoAbbrev.Checked = True Then
            txtAbbrev.Text = ""
            txtAbbrev.Focus()
        Else
            txtCountry.Text = ""
            txtCountry.Focus()

        End If
    End If
    'reset variables
    Counter = 0
    Found = False
End Sub
'exit button click event
Private Sub btnExit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
'clear button click event
Private Sub btnClear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    rdoAbbrev.Checked = False
    rdoCountry.Checked = False
    txtAbbrev.Text = ""
    txtAbbrev.ReadOnly = True
    txtCountry.Text = ""
    txtCountry.ReadOnly = True
    lblAbbrev.Visible = False
    lblName.Visible = False
    lblTitle.Focus()

End Sub
'radio button selected event
Private Sub rdoCountry_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles rdoCountry.CheckedChanged, rdoAbbrev.CheckedChanged
    Dim ButtonSelected As RadioButton

    ButtonSelected = CType(sender, RadioButton)

    Select Case ButtonSelected.Name
        Case "rdoAbbrev"
            lblName.Text = "Matching Name:  "
            txtCountry.Text = ""
            lblName.Visible = True
            txtCountry.ReadOnly = True
            lblAbbrev.Text = "Enter Abbreviation:  "
            lblAbbrev.Visible = True
            txtAbbrev.ReadOnly = False
            txtAbbrev.Focus()

        Case Else
            lblName.Text = "Enter Name:  "
            lblName.Visible = True
            txtCountry.ReadOnly = False
            txtCountry.Focus()
            lblAbbrev.Text = "Matching Abbreviation:  "
            lblAbbrev.Visible = True
            txtAbbrev.ReadOnly = True
            txtAbbrev.Text = ""
    End Select


End Sub
'user uses browse button to select file
Private Sub btnBrowse_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBrowse.Click
    Dim DialogueResponse As DialogResult
    Dim IndexInteger As Integer

    If sr IsNot Nothing Then
        sr.Close()
    End If

    With OpenFileDialog1
        .InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
        .FileName = "Country.txt"
        .Title = "Select File or Directory for File"
        DialogueResponse = .ShowDialog
    End With

    If DialogueResponse <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        sr = New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If

    Do Until sr.Peek = -1
        If IndexInteger <= 256 Then
            Country(IndexInteger).Abbreviation = sr.ReadLine
            Country(IndexInteger).Names = sr.ReadLine
            IndexInteger += 1
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    sr.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you tell us on what line it crashes ? Step into your code line by line and set breakpoints as needed.

Comment: When I enter invalid information dewpending on which radio button is selected it crashes at the "Found = Country(Counter).Abbreviation.ToUpper = txtAbbrev.Text.ToUpper"  or the "Found = Country(Counter).Names.ToUpper = txtCountry.Text.ToUpper"  lines

Answer (score 1):

apparently the exception was being thrown because the array and loops were set to search through more objects than the file contained.

this issue has been resolved

-solved-